# Convert array to list of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

I have an object

```
myObject = {
  10: "some value",
  15: "another value",
  ...
}
```

can I with underscore, jquery, or plain js convert it into a list as:

```
myList = [
  { label: 10, value: "some value" },
  { label: 15, value: "another value" },
  ...
]
```

Comment: It looks more like you want to convert an object to an array with objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**With underscore.js**

```
myList = _.map(_.pairs(myObject), function(n){
     return {label: n[0], value: n[1]}
});
```

**Or with plain JavaScript**

```
myList = Object.keys(myObject).map(function(key){
    return {label: key, value: myObject[key]}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**map**](http://underscorejs.org/#map) to transform the object into the required form:

```
    var myList = _.map(myObject, function(value, key){
        return {
            label: key,
            value: value
        }
    });
```